# Is not enough for a sequence being monotonic and bounded for $n \geq n_0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am studying Sequences and Series, and doing some exercises I realized that I could use the convergence result for monotonic sequences.

The sequence is bounded, but just monotonic for $n \geq n_0$, where $n_0$ is a fixed positive integer. The theorem still holds ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the theorem still hold. The sequence converges towards the superior bound.

Answer (score 0):

Of course. A finite prefix of a sequence never affect its limit.

Comment: Thanks man, you two helped me a lot. I am giving the right answer mark for Tsemo because he answered first.